# Show that $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is complete if and only if $(X,|\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!|)$ is complete when both norms are equivalent.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

**Problem:** *"Suppose that on the same normed linear space, $X$, you have two equivalent norms, $\|\cdot\|$ and $|\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!|$. Show that $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is complete if and only if $(X,|\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!|)$ is complete."*

**My attempt:** Recall that if two norms are equivalent then $\exists\, a,b\in\mathbb R^+$ such that $a\|x\|\le|\!|\!|x|\!|\!|\le b\|x\|,\,\forall x\in X$. Also recall that a normed linear space is complete if every Cauchy sequence of elements converges to it's limit *in* the space.

Suppose, then, that $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is complete and consider a Cauchy sequence of elements in $X$, $(x_n)$, which converges to it's limit $x\in X$. Then $\|x_n-x\|\to0$ as $n\to\infty.$ But then we have that,

$$a\|x_n-x\|\le|\!|\!|x_n-x|\!|\!|\le b\|x_n-x\|,\,\forall n\in\mathbb N$$

$$\implies0\le|\!|\!|x_n-x|\!|\!|\le0,\,\forall n\in\mathbb N$$

Which means thats $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence in $X$ under $|\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!|$. But we know in a metric space that convergent sequences are necessarily Cauchy. Hence this Cauchy sequence converges to it's limit in $X$ under $|\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!|$. This $(X,|\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!|)$ is complete. A completely analogous argument holds for the other implication.

**Is my attempt and reasoning correct?** My uncertainty stems from the solutions I have to this problem from my class. There, the lecturer has shown seperately that $(x_n)$ converges in one norm iff it converges in the other norm, *and* that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in one norm iff it is Cauchy in the other. Is it not sufficient to merely show the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reasoning is not good enough. Actually one should assume first that $(x_{n})$ is Cauchy in $|\|\cdot\||$ and $\|\cdot\|$ is complete. Then there is some $\|x_{n}-x_{m}\|\leq C|\|x_{n}-x_{m}\||\rightarrow 0$, so $(x_{n})$ is Cauchy in $\|\cdot\|$. Then there is some $x\in X$ such that $\|x_{n}-x\|\rightarrow 0$. Since $|\|x_{n}-x\||\leq D\|x_{n}-x\|\rightarrow 0$, so $(x_{n})$ converges to $x$ in $|\|\cdot\||$.

And by symmetry one does in the other way as well.

Comment: I quite like your approach. Could you perhaps explain in a little more detail why the reasoning I employed isn't good enough?

Comment: Because you assume at the very first that $(x_{n})$ converges to $x$, this is a little bit far away from the assumption of being Cauchy.

Comment: But I'm assuming that $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is complete so that this Cauchy sequence is assumed to attain it's limit in $X$. So I'm not merely assuming that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy and that it converges to it's limit in $X$; this is guaranteed from the completeness assumption.

Comment: In your reasoning, you should assume that $(x_{n})$ is Cauchy in $|\|\cdot\||$, and $\|\cdot\|$ is complete, and try to show that $|\|\cdot\||$ satisfies the convergence, if this succeeds, then $\|\cdot\|$ complete implies $|\|\cdot\||$ complete.

Comment: I'm sorry to be dragging this on, but I want to be entirely sure I have the reasoning correct. In my attempt above I used the fact that a convergent sequence is necessarily Cauchy; but not *every* Cauchy sequence is convergent. So the reason that my attempt is not sufficient is because it doesn't cover all Cauchy sequences, right? In comparison to your attempt, which shows necessarily that since the space is complete *all* Cauchy sequences must be convergent in the space.

Comment: Actually my point is that, if you want to show that $\|\cdot\|$ complete implies $|\|\cdot\||$ complete, you show start to assume that $(x_{n})$ is Cauchy in $|\|\cdot\||$ and try to show $(x_{n})$ is convergent under $|\|\cdot\||$. If you start assuming that $(x_{n})$ is Cauchy in $\|\cdot\|$, actually this does not address the issue in question.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense - thanks again for taking the time to clarify it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $m\|\cdot\| \le |\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!| \le M\|\cdot\|$ for some constants $m,M > 0$.

Take a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $\|\cdot\|$.

Then we have

$$|\!|\!|x_k - x_n|\!|\!| \le M\|x_k - x_n\| \xrightarrow{k,n\to\infty} 0$$

so $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is also Cauchy in $|\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!|$.

Similarly, take a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $|\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!|$.

Then we have

$$\|x_k-x_n\| \le \frac1m|\!|\!|x_k - x_n|\!|\!| \xrightarrow{k,n\to\infty} 0$$

so $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is also Cauchy in $\|\cdot\|$.

Exactly the same reasoning shows that $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges in $\|\cdot\|$ to $x \in X$ if and only if it converges in $|\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!|$ to  the same $x$. Therefore, $\|\cdot\|$ and $|\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!|$ have the same Cauchy sequences and the same convergent sequences.

Therefore, the implication $$\text{ Cauchy } \implies \text{ convergent }$$ is true for $\|\cdot\|$ if and only if it is true for $|\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!|$.

---

The converse also holds, sort of.

Lemma:

> Let $\|\cdot\|$ and $|\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!|$ be two norms on $X$ such that for all sequences $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $X$ we have:
>
> $$(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \text{ Cauchy in } \|\cdot\| \implies (x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \text{ bounded in } |\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!|$$
>
> Then there exists $M > 0$ such that $|\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!| \le M\|\cdot\|$.

Proof: Assume there does not exist such a constant $M$. Then you can construct a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\|x_n\| = 1$ and $|\!|\!|x_n|\!|\!| > n^2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\left\|\frac1n x_n\right\| = \frac1n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$ so $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is convergent (so in particular Cauchy) in $\|\cdot\|$. Therefore $\left(\frac1n x_n\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ must be bounded in $|\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!|$ which is a contradiction.

As a consequence, we get that if $\|\cdot\|$ and $|\!|\!|\cdot|\!|\!|$ have the same Cauchy sequences (or the same convergent sequences), they are necessarily equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a direct way to demonstrate this, by using preservation of the property under certain mappings.

Let $ \left(E, \| \|_{1} \right)$ and $ \left(E, \| \|_{2} \right)$ two $\mathbb{K}$ finite dimensionial vector space. 
Consider the following application:

\begin{aligned}
 \left(E, \| \|_{1} \right) & \rightarrow \left(E, \| \|_{2} \right)  \\
x  &  \mapsto  x 
\end{aligned}
which is a linear lipschitz (using the equivalence of the two norms) continuous bijection (thus, a homeomorphism).

The pre-image of a complete space by a uniformly continuous and bijective function being complete it follows that $\left(E, \| \|_{1} \right)$ is complete if and only if $\left(E, \| \|_{2} \right)$ is complete.